list 'typeLst' variables in json file
I have it installed OpenModelica on two different computers and the file based on the simulation results is structurally different. In one case, the variables in the json file have a list 'typeLst', and in the file on the other computer, this list is missing from the variables.
enter image description here
Can you tell me why this is so? I suppose it is somehow related to the simulation flags, but I did not configure anything on either computer.
